# how to show a sequence of finite-rank operators converges uniformly

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $G\in L^2(0,1)^2$. Define a linear mapping $A:L^2(0,1)\mapsto L^2(0,1)$ such that
$$
Af(x):=\int_0^1G(x,\xi)f(\xi)d\xi,\quad \forall f\in L^2(0,1).
$$
Since $L^2(0,1)$ is a separable Hilbert space, one can choose a Hilbert basis of $L^2(0,1)$ denoted by $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$. Define finite-rank operators $T_n(n\in\mathbb{N}^{+})$  as follows
$$
T_nf:=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left\langle f,e_i\right\rangle e_i,\quad f\in L^2(0,1),
$$
where $\left\langle\cdot,\cdot\right\rangle$ denotes the usual inner product in $L^2(0,1)$. How to prove that
$$
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}||T_nAT_n-A||=0,
$$
where $||\cdot||$ denotes the operator norm induced by the norm on $L^2(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [well-known, that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator) $G\in L^2((0,1)\times (0,1))$ implies that $A$ is a compact operator. As we are on a separable Hilbert space by, e.g., [Lemma 3.3.c in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.01023.pdf), all that is left to show that $T_n$ converges strongly to the identity (because then $T_nAT_n\to \operatorname{id}A\operatorname{id}=A$ in norm as you wanted).

Now $T_n$ is said to converge strongly to $\operatorname{id}$ if for all $x\in L^2$, one has $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|T_nx-x\|_{L^2}=0$. This however holds in arbitrary separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces as is [easily seen](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/214761/495075) using the Fourier expansion and Parseval's identity.

Comment: Actually, I just want to prove the proposition to further prove that $A$ is compact. So, without using the fact that $A$ is compact, how to show $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}||T_nAT_n-A||=0$? Or can I just show $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}||T_n-I||=0$?

Comment: In that case, Theorem 1 [here](http://www-m15.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/M15/Allgemeines/IllposedProblems/WebHome/board11.pdf) should be of interest for you. This is essentially your idea, only that one considers $T_nA$ (finite-rank operators) and directly shows $\|T_nA-A\|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: yes, you are correct. Let me share you with another proof of compactness of $A$. The kernel can be approximated by step function $k_n$ that is piece-wise constants on small rectangle and then define $A_n$ equipped with kernel $k_n$. Such $A_n$ is compact, since $A_n(f)$ is always a simple function with the same characteristic partition and range of $A_n$ is finite and thus $A_n$ compact and then $A$ compact. It seems that it is ridiculous to try to prove $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}||T_n-I||=0$, since $I$ is surely not compact in infinite dimension setting.